# stripping default wordpress code out of a page

Tags: html

I am trying to make a page in wordpress with my own unique html code, so my own head, html, body tags etc... I cant get it to work but then wordpress chucks in its own head , html tags etc so it adds spaces on the page,

is there a way to strip the wordpress code out of one page, and use the code you want?

Possible some how?

Answer (score 2):

Use [custom page template](http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages#Creating_Your_Own_Page_Templates) and you will have complete control over what goes in that page.